# Parse background job - Parse.Query.each() promise behavior

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, jobs

thanks for stopping by to help!

I have a background job I have to rewrite using Parse.Query.each(), as I now have several thousand objects, and the number will continue to grow over my product's life cycle. [Here's a link to Parse.Query.each()'s documentation.](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Query.html#each)

I have to query through two different sets of objects for two custom classes, and depending on the data, modify an array of objects of a third custom class. I am trying to use promises to perform both queries then save my array of objects. However, my first query returns an error, and trying to access the error message is throwing an error since it says the error is undefined.  I am unable to debug my code, as I can't get a relevant error message to figure out why the first query is not succeeding.

Here's my code setup, where I'm trying to use promises in conjunction with Query.each:

```
//set up queries
query1.each
(
    function( object1 )
    {
        {//do stuff modifying arrayOfObject3s}
    }
).then
(
    function( results )
    {
        return query2.each
        (
            function( object2 )
            {//do more stuff modifying arrayOfObject3s}
        );
    },
    function( error )
    {
        //This is the line I'm getting an error at, saying "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined at..."
        status.error("There was an error while performing query1: " + error.message); 
    }
).then
(
    function( results )
    {
        return Parse.Object.saveAll( arrayOfObject3s);
    },
    function( error )
    {
        status.error("There was an error performing query2: " + error.message)
    }
).then
(
    function( arrayOfObject3s )
    {
        status.success("Performed the queries and saved the objects!");
    },
    function( error )
    {
        status.error("There was an error while saving the objects: " + error.message);
    }
);
```

I'm clearly misunderstanding something about how to use query.each along with parse promises, because my job immediately fails with an error saying "Cannot read property 'message' of undefined at..." and gives the line number of the first `function( error )` in the first `.then()` block. I have tried both what you see above, and one without `results` in the first function for both of the first two `.then()` blocks, getting the same error.

If you have any suggestions to set this up properly, please let me know. I am a novice with these promises, and this is my first time trying to use query.each().